# How to convert PostgresQL command to SQL query builder syntax

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, pg-promise

I have the following Postgres command:

```
UPDATE users SET weightsovertime = weightsovertime || '{"weight":35,"date":"1/9/97"}'::jsonb where id = 20;
```

and I would like to convert it into SQL query builder command using libraries such as Knex.js.

I tried this:

```
postgres('users')
.where('id','=',id)
.update({
    weightsovertime: weightsovertime +'||' + data + '::jsonb' 
})
.returning('weightsovertime')
.then(response => {
    res.json(response[0]);
})
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'));
```

But it does not work, I also tried to wrap the 'weightsovertime' in quotation marks but I got the error 'unable to get entries'.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are using `pg-promise`, then why such complication? It is just a single-line query with `pg-promise`.

Comment: I tried pg promise, but it didn’t work either

Comment: What didn't work? If you post details, then you can get an answer.

Comment: db.any('UPDATE users SET weightsovertime = weightsovertime || 'data'::jsonb where id = id);

Answer (score 0):

With knex (https://runkit.com/embed/3ppka63pplpa):

```
knex('users').update({
  weightsovertime: knex.raw('?? || ?::jsonb', [
    'weightsovertime', 
    JSON.stringify({ weight: 35, date: '1/9/97' })
  ])
}).where('id', 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) it would be:

```
const data = {
    id: 20,
    weightsovertime: {
        weight: 35,
        date: '1/9/97'
    }
};

db.none('UPDATE users SET weightsovertime = weightsovertime || ${weightsovertime}::jsonb WHERE id = ${id}', data)
    .then(() => {
        /* success */
    })
    .catch(error => {
         /* failure */
    });
```